# Nested select lists and loading information

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have the following code of two select lists the second one is showing information depending on the selection of the first one :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include-js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="standing_countries" name="standing_countries">
                    <option class="country_element" id='1'>Ingiltere</option>
                    <option class="country_element" id='2'>Türkiye</option>
                    <option class="country_element" id='3'>Almanya</option>
                    <option class="country_element" id='4'>Ispanya</option>
                    <option class="country_element" id='5'>Italya</option>
                    <option class="country_element" id='6'>Fransa</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class='leagues' id='leagues'>
                <select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                    <option class='league_element' id='1204'>Premier League</option>
                    <option class='league_element' id='1205'>Şampiyona</option>
                    <option class='league_element' id='1206'>League One</option>
                    <option class='league_element' id='1197'>League Two</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.standing_countries').on('change',function(){
        var select_id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        if(select_id == 1)
        {
            var txt="<select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1204'>Premier League</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1205'>Şampiyona</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1206'>League One</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1197'>League Two</option>";
                txt=txt +"</select>";
            $('.leagues').html(txt);
        }
        else if(select_id == 2)
        {
            var txt="<select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1425'>Spor Toto Süper Lig</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1422'>Ptt 1.Lig</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1421'>Spor Toto Tff 2.Lig</option>";
                txt=txt +"</select>";
            $('.leagues').html(txt);
        }
        else if(select_id == 3)
        {
            var txt="<select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1229'>Bundesliga</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1225'>2.Bundesliga</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1230'>3.Liga</option>";
                txt=txt +"</select>";
            $('.leagues').html(txt);
        }
        else if(select_id == 4)
        {
            var txt="<select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1399'>Primera Division</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1398'>Segunda Division</option>";
                txt=txt +"</select>";
            $('.leagues').html(txt);
        }
        else if(select_id == 5)
        {
            var txt="<select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1269'>Serie A</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1265'>Serie B</option>";
                txt=txt +"</select>";
            $('.leagues').html(txt);
        }
        else if(select_id == 6)
        {
            var txt="<select class='standing_leagues' name='standing_leagues'>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1221'>League 1</option>";
                txt=txt +"<option class='league_element' id='1217'>League 2</option>";
                txt=txt +"</select>";
            $('.leagues').html(txt);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.standing_leagues').on('change',function(){
        var standing_id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        alert(standing_id);
    });
});
```

I wrote some jQuery code to alert when the second list option is selected and it worked just for the first (default list), but when I choose an option from the first list and the information is loaded to the second list, I try to select an option from the second list, but no alert is triggered.

Can anybody help me? I am new to jQuery with lists, what is going on?

Comment: Can you share the fiddle ?

Comment: Even if it should be no problem in modern browsers, it is better to start an ID with a letter not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is because you are creating the select box every time you change the country.

You need to bind the event after you create the select box.

Answer (score 0):

Its because use change the html so event cannot work you need to add event listener every time like this

```
function bindEvent(){
   $('.standing_leagues').on('change',function(){
       var standing_id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
       alert(standing_id);
   });
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJHxd/)

Call that function on every time you change the html of `.leagues` class